# Stop audio when app go to the background in flutter with just_audio package

Tags: android, ios, flutter, just-audio, background-audio

I have a flutter app that use just_audio package to listen music. When my app go in the background, the audio don't stop and i'm not using audio_service or just_audio_background.

How can I do the most simply way to just stop the music when the app go in the background, without using audio_service or just_audio_background if possible.

Thanks !

Comment: Can you try with overriding `dispose` and calling `yourPlayer.stop();`

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh I already do that, my dispose function contains player.dispose(); and it works if I change pages in my menu but doesn't work if the app goes to the background.